# invalid resource directory name: E:\workspace\.........\res red.png

Tags: android

I've been stuck on this ,

```
I have saved "red.png" in res folder,,but still getting error as
"invalid resource directory name: E:\workspace\.........\res red.png",
```

I tried

```
 1.cleaning and rebuilding project
 2.restart the eclipse
 3.pasted "red.png" in sub folders of drawable ,
```

but not getting the solution.
please suggest me

Comment: this is improper directory name...that would be \res\red.png..

Comment: why you are getting this error... did you try to get file from folder ?

Comment: This isn't a valid path: `E:\workspace\.........\res red.png`

Comment: @Tanimreja i am trying to use that image in my layout

Comment: Do you by chance still have a `red.png` lying around in the top level `res` folder, i.e. `res\red.png`?

Comment: @dhke ,no its not present

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,,

```
created a folder named "drawable" 
and pasted the image inside that folder,
```

thanks for your valuable response

Answer (score 0):

There is easy way to use a image file in layout from res/drawable folder..
put this image in drawable folder and write in your xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/red"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

dont use file extention like .png

Answer (score 0):

In android you can not set images directly to res folder , `For putting images ***you have to create drawable folders*** like drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi etc` because in android we have many resolutions .

For more understanding please take a look at below link

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html